# How to add only one data in database table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am creating a site and i am making a general option page for the site that include the site name, logo, social links so that i can manage them dynamically from one place without changing the links and text in all pages where i called them.

What I want is that the table i created in database, i want to have only one row in it. If someone try to add other row of data it should not be added because i have to call only one data for the site.

I hope the query is clear to all. 
Thanks for your support. Help me if u can. please :)

Comment: then why you providing form to user to add record?

Comment: usually in such cases people use is_active field and only fetch only active rows from the table

Comment: Instead of using the Database table you can store those values in [Laravel Config](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration) File or simply you can use those settings from `.env` file also since you are using Laravel.

Comment: @bluemoon because to edit   social links or logo by form

Comment: please show edit method

Comment: only authenticated user can edit?

Comment: @bluemoon yes. page is accessable to admin only.

Comment: if you show your code it will be easy to provide solution

Comment: simple solution is that create a db field in users table is_admin set it to 1 by default after that make a check as if(Auth::user()->is_admin){ //edit code here }else{// go here  }

Answer (score 0):

By,

> if someone try to add other row of data it should not be added

what do you mean? Are you trying to avoid unauthorized access? If yes, then you need to implement roles https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/roles-and-permissions-in-laravel-5

To manage your site information, I'm sure you set a form that will be used to update the site info. And from the look of things you will only be updating that row when you hit save or update button. I don't think you will be doing full CRUD here just updating so there'll be no chance of inserting a new row of data in the db.

So three things:

- you want to create a migration, seed the table with the site details accordingly. run the migration
- you want to make sure the user trying to access this route is authorized to do so
- you want to pre populate the site info in the form fields when the edit site info page loads and you want to save the form when the authorized user changes any of the site info

This way, there'll be no question of stopping further insertions into the db.